# If the last column is equal "R" then... Is it possible? In unix

Tags: unix, if-statement, awk, ksh, equals-operator

I need to find the last column from a variable that contains some fields. I need to write something like:

```
    if [ #the last column = "R" ];
    then
    value=`echo "'$value'"`
    fi
```

Is it possible?

Comment: [`man 3 cut`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_(Unix))

Comment: Yes but think that i don't know how many cols there are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More universal code assuming separation by spaces:

```
case $var in
  (*\ R) printf "%s\n" "$var"
esac
```

Or:

```
if [ "${var##* }" = R ]; then
  printf "%s\n" "$var"
fi
```

Answer (score 9):

With `awk` you can try:

```
awk '$NF=="R"' <<< "$var"
```

#### Test:

```
$ var="this is a var with last as R"
$ awk '$NF=="R"' <<< "$var"
this is a var with last as R
$ var1="This should not be printed"
$ awk '$NF=="R"' <<< "$var1"
$
```

Comment: No, thank you.  And just in case the OP really needs to use it in a conditional rather than having the result print to the screen: `if awk '$NF == "R" { exit 0 }; { exit 1 }' <<< "$var"` might do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

The condition can be:

```
if [[ $value == *' 'R ]]
then
    echo $value
fi
```

No need for an external language, like `awk`.

Comment: `*` means "zero or more of any character", as it would in `*.txt`.  `' '` is just a space (which I assume is your column delimiter), it needs to be quoted because a space is also a shell delimiter.  You might be able to get away with `*R`, but that would also pickup something like "RIVER".

Comment: You should use `*[[:space:]]R` instead, in case the columns are tab-delimited

Answer (score 2):

Using the `=~` binary operator:

```
$ var="Some arbitrary string ending in R"
$ unset value
$ [[ "$var" =~ $'R$' ]] && value=${var}
$ echo $value
Some arbitrary string ending in R
$ var="Some arbitrary string ending in Q"
$ unset value
$ [[ "$var" =~ $'R$' ]] && value=${var}
$ echo $value
```

Comment: +1! I add a minor change. IMHO it is not the last "column", just the last last character. So it would be `[[ $var =~ [[:space:]]R$ ]] && echo Last column is R`.